# Windows 7 PC takes a long time to connect to the internet

Tags: windows-7, router

On startup my Windows 7 computer connects to my Zyxel router via cable connection. The router already has a connection to the internet, as my mobile devices are able to access it but the PC takes a couple of minutes (or more) to connect to the internet. The network symbol on the bottom toolbar displays a light blue circle until the connection is finally established. How can I find out what is causing the delay?

Comment: Hard to tell where the problem is. Some troubleshooting would have to done: Trying the same wired connection in a different network and trying other wired devices in the same router.

Comment: Have you tried the Troubleshooting tool?  Go to Control Panel → Troubleshooting, or click “Start” and type “troublesh…”.

Comment: Previously I had problems occasionally when the network connection was dropped during an online session and I received a prompt to sign into my network. Then the router's control panel appeared. I ran the Windows troubleshooter which identified DNS problems. So I entered the OpenDNS addresses in the network adaptor settings and in the router and this has seemed to cured that problem - but the internet connection still takes a long time to be established - despite it being available on other devices using the router's wifi.